# Creating a file as root in android

Tags: java, android, root

I'm trying to write a little App to restore some data.
Of course the phone is rooted and the emulator, too...

So, I have a ZIP-file with some directories. I want to recreate the directories and files, using a Process-Session started with "su".

I create the directories with "mkdir /data/...". No problem!

Now I want to create the files. I know, that I can create a file under Linux with "cat > /path/to/file", then sending data and closing all with "CTRL+D", so I wanted to do that in the App, too.

Hier my code:

```
      dos.writeBytes("cat > /tmp/x/mybackup/" + ze.getName() + "\n");
      while((byteCount = this.zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
      {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
      }
      dos.write(4); // CTRL+d
      dos.flush();
```

Well, I can create the file, but just **one** file, and the content is the concatenated content of all file, that I extract from ZIP...
It seems, that my "CTRL+D" will be ignored.

Could you help me and say what I'm doing wrong? Or suggest a better solutions...

Thanks a lot
Luca

Comment: Assuming you're using BusyBox, I'd use mktemp first. http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

Comment: What is in the variable `dos`?

Comment: I'm not using BusyBox, since it's not present on my old phone and I want to develop a "general" App... Do you mean, that I have to save the Data in a temporary file and the copy them to the correct path?

Comment: @Henry: Variable dos is DataOutputStream, got from Process

Comment: So you are unzipping/extracting a zip file. Please show more code complete with the mkdirs and determining the different files in the zip. What is ze?

Comment: ze is a ZipEntry. The problem is in this code part. I can't send the "CTRL+D" to the cat, and then all data are written in the first file.